# Change all Elements (html) of a div on changing the language?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown menu on my page which has language selector options. on selecting the language i want my labels and buttons html to be changed according to the language?
**My Code**

```
var arr = [];
    //  gets all the ids starting with comp_
    $('div[id^="comp_"]').each(function(){
        arr.push(this.id);
        labels = $(this).find('label');
        buttons = $(this).find('button');

        //get all labels inside the current div
        $(labels,buttons).each(function(){
            $(this).html("");
        });

    });
    console.log(arr);
},
```

**Problem **
It only changes the label element reference and not the button reference.can i run the function on multiple element references?

**It Works if I do this but i dont want to repeat the same code again for diffferent references**

```
    var arr = [];
    //  gets all the ids starting with comp_
    $('div[id^="comp_"]').each(function(){
        arr.push(this.id);
        labels = $(this).find('label');
        buttons = $(this).find('button');

        //get all labels inside the current div
        $(labels).each(function(){
            $(this).html("");
        });

        $(buttons).each(function(){
            $(this).html("");
        });

    });
    console.log(arr);
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

```
    labels.add(buttons).each(function(){
        $(this).html("");
    });
```

Or just:

```
    labels.add(buttons).html('');
```

One character shorter:

```
    labels.add(buttons).empty();
```

The `.add()` jQuery method is used to add elements to an existing jQuery collection.  Those examples use `.add()` to combine the elements in the "labels" and "buttons" jQuery objects.  The second two are to indicate that you don't need `.each()` if you're doing something invariable to each element. Most jQuery functions intrinsically operate on every element of the collection.

Totally different way to simplify:

```
    var labelsAndButtons = $(this).find('label, button');
    labelsAndButtons.empty();
```

The `,` in a selector string is like "or".  That example finds all elements whose tag name is "label" **or** "button".

Comment: Right on ...If you can explain what the above code does ? it works just want to know how coz i might need to add more element references..thanks

Comment: @user2125700 ok well I added a little more detail.